# If interested in common a trend in multiple groups, can I pool all the data and run a correlation rather than an ANCOVA?

Tags: regression, correlation, interaction, ancova

Dear CrossValidated Community,

I have three groups, each of which has some biological data I'll call X, and I am interested in whether X is correlated with their treatment response, Y.

Thus far, I have been running an ANCOVA model, in which y ~ treatmentgroup*X. From my understanding, this will provide the main effects of the treatment group, X, and their interaction, potentially unveiling differences in the slopes of the treatment group.

However, what if I am not interested in the difference in slopes, but finding a "common" slope amongst all three groups, to ultimately be able to make the claim that their slopes are similar. Can I pool the data of the three groups, and run a correlation to make this claim?

Intuitively, I feel it is wrong to do so, but am not sure what the alternative is. Perhaps running an ANCOVA but restraining the lines to be parallel (in other words, removing the interaction)?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you want to drop the interaction term. That will force the slopes to all be equal. Careful, though...what if the slopes aren’t equal? What does graphical examination show? Are your interaction terms significant? How different are the slopes, different enough to care? It’s a judgment call if you want to include the interaction, and I don’t understand your rationale for wanting to drop it, though it sounds like, “I wish the slopes were the same, so I’ll force them to be.”